# Xcode 4.5.1 new warning (potentially insecure)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I upgraded my Xcode to Version 4.5.1 and suddenly previous app development had 'potentially insecure' during build.

it generally applies to declaring this type of construct:

```
NSString *userChoice = [NSString stringWithFormat:label1a.text]; //Warning at pulling string from label1a.text
[usrAnswer setObject:userChoice forKey:@"1"];
```

is this a serious warning? How do i rectify this?

Comment: This is not a new warning by any means.  This warning has been around for many versions.

Comment: Well it just popped up after the update... Wasn't around before... What could be the reason i wonder...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using a format string. Just do this:

```
NSString *userChoice = label1a.text;
```

I see a lot of people create strings with stringWithFormat:. Only use that when you are actually creating a string with format specifiers.

Comment: Or even more simply, just use labella.text as the as the argument for setObject: and delete the first line entirely.

Comment: Yes, that will work too. But I prefer keeping things split up a bit. It makes the code easier to read and easier to debug. Personal preference.